# How do you submit hidden field input for Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, safari, mobile-safari

I am adding input to a hidden html field on a form via jQuery before submission.

The input added to the hidden field is a value taken from a cookie.

We've had hundreds of submits and everything works fine across all devices and browsers except for **Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView** browsers. I have confirmed that it is not a cookie blocking issue with these browsers but that the issue lies with either the treatment of the form itself or the javascript/jQuery that adds a value to the hidden field.

Do these browsers block javascript? Does my javascript need to be placed in a separate .js file instead of inline? Do resources need to be loaded in a certain order?

Here is the jQuery that adds the value to the hidden field pre-submission:

```
<script>
    $("#lp-pom-button-19").click(function() {
      var kiss_id = KM.i();
      $("#kissmetrics_id").val(kiss_id);
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why you sent a cookie value to the server? Server gets all the cookies on request. Also post your html code (or some of it). (Some browsers do block javascript.)